# Undertanding a low pass filter code in image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The aim of this piece of Matlab code is to smooth a horizontal histogram by applying a low pass filter.

First horizontal and vertical histograms representing the sum of differences of gray values between neighboring pixels of an image, column-wise and row-wise were used. The horizontal histogram is named horz1 so horz1(i)=sum where 'i' is the column number and 'sum' is the sum of differences. Then, a low pass filter was applied. I don't understand the 'applying low pass filter' part.I don't know much about Image processing. If anyone could help me understand I would really appreciate it.

```
   %% horizontal histogram
    disp('Processing Edges Horizontally...');
    max_horz = 0;
    maximum = 0;
    for i = 2:cols
        sum = 0;
    for j = 2:rows
            if(I(j, i) > I(j-1, i))
                difference = uint32(I(j, i) - I(j-1, i));
            else
                difference = uint32(I(j-1, i) - I(j, i));
           end
            if(difference > 20)
                sum = sum + difference;
           end
        end
horz1(i) = sum;
%%applying low pass filter
sum = 0;
horz = horz1;
for i = 21:(cols-21)
    sum = 0;
    for j = (i-20):(i+20)
        sum = sum + horz1(j);
    end
    horz(i) = sum / 41;
end
```

end

Comment: It simply finds the average over a 41 element window.  Low-pass filter retains low-frequency components and suppresses high frequency components.  Averaging is an example of a low-pass filter.

Comment: Thank you. Well about the line : for i=21:(cols - 21) what is it for? aren't we taking 41 elements by selecting j from (i-20) to (i+20)?

Comment: It starts at `i = 21` because it needs to collect 20 values before and after **without** going out of bounds including the middle: 20 + 20 + 1 = 41. When `i = 21`, then `j = 1` to `41`, then when `i = 22`, `j = 2` to `42` etc. up to `cols - 21`, which `j = cols-41` up to `cols-1`. Technically we should end  at `i = cols-20` though, but that's ok.  The loop controlled by `i` determines what the centre of the window is and the loop controlled by `j` collects the right samples dictated by `i`.  You'll need to think about it especially if you aren't used to this, but eventually it will make sense.

Comment: This is an algorithm for car plate extraction from an image. Why do you think he used the low pass filter in the first place?

Comment: That's to smoothen out the histograms so that it allows the transitions between the foreground and background to be easier in detection.

Comment: What do you mean 'easier' ?

Comment: There is a potential that the horizontal scanlines may be noisy so that there are local peaks as you are progressing through the scanline.  This is a direct result of noise.  Performing a low-pass filter smoothens those peaks so that it's much easier to find transitions between foreground and background and not get any false positives.  You are doing this for both horizontal and vertical so you can localize and find the bounding box of where the car plate would be located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply finds the average over a 41 element window. Low-pass filter retains low-frequency components and suppresses high frequency components. Averaging is an example of a low-pass filter.

The explanation of the two `for` loops at the end when calculating the filtered output is as follows.  It starts at `i = 21` because it needs to collect 20 values before and after without going out of bounds including the middle: `20 + 20 + 1 = 41`. When `i = 21`, then `j = 1` to `41`, then when `i = 22`, `j = 2 to 42` etc. up to `cols - 21`, which is thus `j = cols - 41` up to `cols - 1`. Technically we should end at `i = cols - 20` though, but that's ok if you want to miss calculating the final valid output of the signal.

The loop controlled by `i` determines what the centre of the window is and the loop controlled by `j` collects the right samples dictated by `i`. You'll need to think about it especially if you aren't used to this, but eventually it will make sense.